# how to turn off auto complete on the outlook browser version

Tags: microsoft-outlook

It is so annoying and forces typos if you disagree with their suggestion and tries more than once to enforce their suggestion.
How do I turn this off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an absolutely annoying feature.  You can turn it off in settings, the feature is called "Text predictions":

Settings (the little 'gear' icon in the upper right, then click "View all Outlook settings")-->Compose and reply-->(scroll down to the "Text predictions" section)-->uncheck "Suggest words or phrases as I type."

Be sure to click "Save" after unchecking this.

You can also uncheck "Offer suggestions based on keywords in my messages" and "Show suggested replies" if you want to turn off all of the auto suggestions.  I find that the "Text predictions" are the most annoying.

Comment: I bet they are collecting data on acceptance rates and fine tuning their text prediction model.

Comment: I think you are 100% right about this.  Before I turned it off, mine started often suggesting a very specific word that I use for my job that is not a standard English-language word.

Answer (score 1):

If your account is a exchange account, you could follow the method provided by a similar [thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c6b3b3bf-c904-4e77-89e6-7b7850290ab7/turn-off-autocomplete-in-owa?forum=exchangesvrclientslegacy). Hope it is helpful to you.